# Wordpress get_posts inside WP_Query loop

Tags: wordpress, loops

I have a content template which runs the main loop:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Inside this loop I create a `get_posts()`:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
 'posts_per_page' => '2',
 'category__in' => array(2),
 'post__not_in' => array(get_the_id()),
 'order'    => 'DESC'
);

$posts_array = get_posts($args);
if(isset($posts_array) && !empty($posts_array)) : foreach( $posts_array as $post ) :
?>
 some html
<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```

This works perfectly, but when I am outside of the `foreach` loop and I call `get_the_id()` the `ID` returned is the last one of the `foreach` loop although the documentation states `get_posts()` shouldn't alter any global variables.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the `global $post` that is being set up in The Loop in your `foreach` statement:

```
foreach( $posts_array as $post )
```

Use a different variable name and you shouldn't have an issue:

```
foreach( $posts_array as $my_post )
```